# rule not executing in snakemake workflow for read mapping with bwa, samtools

Tags: snakemake

Trying to set up a basic read mapping workflow.  The read mapping rule runs ok and makes a .sam file,  but snakemake skips the second rule that runs samtools fixmate on that .sam file to make a .bam file.

```
rule all:
    input:
        "{sample}.bam"


rule bwa_map:
    params:
        index="../ref/GCF_000004255.2_v.1.0_genomic"
    input:
        "{sample}_1.fastq",
        "{sample}_2.fastq"
    output:
        "{sample}.sam"
    shell:
        "bwa mem -M -t 6 -r 1 -o {output} {params.index} {input}"

rule fixmate:
        input:
                "{sample}.sam"
        output:
                "{sample}.bam"
        shell:
                "samtools fixmate -O bam {input} {output}"
```

Comment: What do you mean by "skips the second rule"?

Comment: The fixmate rule is not executed.    snakemake -n -j 1 SRR7904933.sam
Building DAG of jobs...
Job counts:
        count   jobs
        1       bwa_map
        1

[Sun Jan 31 11:12:30 2021]
rule bwa_map:
    input: SRR7904933_1.fastq, SRR7904933_2.fastq
    output: SRR7904933.sam
    jobid: 0
    wildcards: sample=SRR7904933

Job counts:
        count   jobs
        1       bwa_map
        1
This was a dry-run (flag -n). The order of jobs does not reflect the order of execution.

Comment: What is the target you are building? The `"{sample}.bam"` cannot be target as the target cannot contain wildcards.

Comment: thanks,   yes I was trying to run it without the full name .   snakemake  A.bam   runs.

Comment: You need to provide more details, the exact Snakefile, how you run it, the existing files, which files are created after you run the script, etc. So far your question cannot be answered.

Comment: sorry for lack of details.  The suggestion helped a lot as  I was not providing the full output name on the command line